# Does power bi embedded bookmarks take a snapshot of the data?

Tags: powerbi-embedded

I was wondering if the bookmarks captures a snapshot of the data?  For example, if the datasource updates the data, will that be reflected in the bookmark or would it display the chart based on the dataset at the time the bookmark was created?

Thanks,
Derek

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Power BI Embedded bookmarks, as well as Power BI bookmarks in powerbi.com, do not capture the data itself rather the visual & report configurations that manipulate the data.

Bookmarks contain visual locations & visibility, filter state & navigation between report pages.

This way you can keep the data updated and refreshable.